# How to use getRequestForUpdate() in Mobile SDK

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, android, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I can't find a detailed explanation in the Mobils SDK Development Guide about how to use the getRequestForUpdate() object.
Is there any freely available tutorial about this?

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty straight forward.

For Android:

getRequestForUpdate basically used ti update a record in Salesforce using rest API. It has following parameter in order:

- String (API Version) Ex: 30.0
- String (SobjectType) Ex: Account or Custom_Object__c
- String (Record Id) Ex: 0010000000eWerTIAA
- Map (Field API Name, Field Value) Ex: {Name => Regal}

Returns a RestRequest class's Object

Sample Example:

```
RestRequest restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForUpdate(getString(R.string.api_version), "Account", "0010000000eWerTIAA", fieldMap);

    restClient.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback() { 
        @Override public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result) { 
             try { 
                    // Play with result object returned of type RestResponse
                    // .. DO MORE
                 } catch (Exception e) { 
                    onError(e); 
                 } 
        }
```

This link would help: http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/mobile_sdk/Content/android_native_tut_detail_page_6.htm